# How to print out left joystick Xbox Once controller on terminal in VS19, .Net Core 3 using XInput?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0, xbox-one, xinput

I am looking to print something on the terminal in VS 2019, .NET Core 3 using SharpDX.XInput for the joystick. Maybe some value -1 if the joystick is pushed to the left and 1 if the joystick is pushed to the right. This is the code I'm currenlty using but I'm stuck with Printing a value to the screen:

namespace XboxC
{
    class Program
    {

```
    Controller controller;
    Gamepad gamepad;
    public bool connected = false;
    public int deadband = 2500;
    public Point leftThumb, rightThumb = new Point(0,0);
    public float leftTrigger, rightTrigger;

    public Program()
    {
        controller = new Controller(UserIndex.One);
        connected = controller.IsConnected;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

    }
    public void Update()
    {
        if (!connected)
            return;

        gamepad = controller.GetState().Gamepad;


        leftThumb.X = (int)((Math.Abs((float)gamepad.LeftThumbX) < deadband) ? 0 : (float)gamepad.LeftThumbX / short.MinValue * -100);
        leftThumb.Y = (int)((Math.Abs((float)gamepad.LeftThumbY) < deadband) ? 0 : (float)gamepad.LeftThumbY / short.MaxValue * 100);
        rightThumb.X = (int)((Math.Abs((float)gamepad.RightThumbX) < deadband) ? 0 : (float)gamepad.RightThumbX / short.MaxValue * 100);
        rightThumb.Y = (int)((Math.Abs((float)gamepad.RightThumbY) < deadband) ? 0 : (float)gamepad.RightThumbY / short.MaxValue * 100);

        leftTrigger = gamepad.LeftTrigger;
        rightTrigger = gamepad.RightTrigger;


    }

}
```

}